# Inversion operator to invert list from random points

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pycharm

Is there any way to Invert list data from some random index.
I don't want to invert whole list, just a slice of it.
Like, we have input list 
 `a=[4,3,6,2,1,5,7,8]` and output list
 `a' = [4,3,5,1,2,6,7,8]`
Inversion point could be anywhere, and preferred to be selected randomly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it possible, you can generate 2 random numbers and use them to select differents index of `a`

```
import random

a = [4,3,6,2,1,5,7,8]

b = random.randint(0,len(a))
c = random.randint(0,len(a))
while c == b :
    c = random.randint(0,len(a))

tmp = a[b]
a[b] = a[c]
a[c] = tmp
print(a)
```

**EDIT :**
Whit the invertion between indexes

```
import random

a = [4,3,6,2,1,5,7,8]


len_a = len(a)-1

b = random.randint(0,len_a)
c = random.randint(0,len_a)
while c == b :
    c = random.randint(0,len_a)

if(b < c):
    min = b
    max = c
else:
    min = c
    max = b

print(f"{min} {max}")

new_list = a[0:min]

if(min == 0):
    for number in a[max::-1]:
        new_list.append(number)
else:
    for number in a[max:min-1:-1]:
        new_list.append(number)



if(max != len(a)):
    for number in a[max+1:len_a+1]:
        new_list.append(number)

print(f"a = \t\t{a}")
print(f"new_list = \t{new_list}")
```

Output :

```
4 6
a =             [4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8]
new_list =      [4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 1, 8]
```

Comment: This would replace only two different indexes. I want to reverse the part of list between those two index like; a = [4,3,6,2,1,5,7,8] so for this if b = 3 and c=1, then a'=[4,1,2,6,3,5,7,8]